# TransportError: TransportError(503, 'search_phase_execution_exception')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, elasticsearch

I'm trying to read documents from an index using Python with Elasticsearch. I get an error I can't find the solution to. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

I've looked online for the same problem, but I can't find any related articles/solutions.

This is my code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from pandasticsearch import Select

# Connection to ElasticSearch
es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'],timeout=600)

# Retrieving all documents in index (no query given)
documents = es.search(index='myindex',body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})

# Convert the result to Pandas Dataframe
pandas_df = Select.from_dict(documents).to_pandas()
```

*Source: https://medium.com/@patni.sonal/elasticsearch-convert-your-index-data-into-pandas-dataframe-30c44ada2407

The error I get is:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search [status:503 request:0.062s]
GET http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search [status:503 request:0.027s]
GET http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search [status:503 request:0.030s]
GET http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search [status:503 request:0.017s]
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-6-68e07be7c100>", line 1, in <module>
documents = es.search(index='myindex',body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})

File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\elasticsearch\client\__init__.py", line 655, in search
doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)

File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 318, in perform_request
status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, 
params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)

File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 185, in 
perform_request
self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)

File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, 
error_message, additional_info)

TransportError: TransportError(503, 'search_phase_execution_exception')
```

This is the elasticsearch log:

```
[2019-04-25T11:19:35,843][DEBUG][o.e.a.s.TransportSearchAction] [Cx6mYd6] All shards failed for phase: [query]
[2019-04-25T11:19:35,845][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] [Cx6mYd6] path: /myindex/_search, params: {index=myindex}
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:293) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:133) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseDone(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:254) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase.onShardFailure(InitialSearchPhase.java:101) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase.lambda$performPhaseOnShard$1(InitialSearchPhase.java:209) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase$1.doRun(InitialSearchPhase.java:188) [elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:759) [elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.TimedRunnable.doRun(TimedRunnable.java:41) [elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
```

Does anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: In error log I can see `documents = es.search(index='myindex',body={})` whereas in code it is `documents = es.search(index='myindex',body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})`. Which line is actually in code?

Comment: Sorry, documents = es.search(index='myindex',body={"query": {"match_all": {}}}) is the actual code. The other one was when I ran the code from the *Source (provided).

Comment: There should be more log info for `TransportError(503, 'search_phase_execution_exception')`. If not then can you add the full log which can be found in elasticsearch logs.

Comment: What response do you get when you access `http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search` in your browser?

Comment: {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[]},"status":503}

Comment: Ok, What for this `http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v`

Comment: index         shard prirep state      docs store ip node
myindex 0     p      UNASSIGNED               
myindex 0     r      UNASSIGNED               
my_index      0     p      UNASSIGNED               
my_index      0     r      UNASSIGNED               
.kibana_1     0     p      UNASSIGNED

Comment: None of the shard is assigned and hence the error. If this is a test index and you don't have any issue in losing data then try deleting the index and create it again.

Comment: A friend is using the same code and same index and it works for her.

Comment: It requires more debugging as why the shards are not getting allocated. Try restarting the elastic node and check the logs. Those logs might help further to find the root cause.

Comment: could you please post the output of pip freeze | grep elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error when sending a request immediately after starting the `elasticsearch` service. After a few seconds, I retried and was able to perform the request successfully.

Comment: same thing happened to me